# Angular-Datatables - How do I make table sortable using default settings?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, datatable, angular-datatables

I am creating a plunker for another question but I cannot get angular-datatables to sort without configuration.

I have code from a project that responds to sorting when users click on header columns but it just does not want to sort in plunkr.

Am I missing any sort of configuration or overlooking anything?

**How do I make the table sortable using default settings?**

Plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/71RqBQ0HF7ThDyZPpc1E?p=info

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="datatables@1.9.4" data-semver="1.9.4" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<script data-require="jquery@1.10.1" data-semver="1.10.1" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="datatables@1.9.4" data-semver="1.9.4" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" data-require="angular.js@1.2.15" data-semver="1.2.15" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgithub.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/dev/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="datatablesSampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="simpleCtrl">
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table  datatable="ng" class="table" >
              <thead style="background-color: #d8d8d8;">
               <tr>
                   <th>Product</th>
                   <th>Tag Name</th>
                   <th>Unit Size</th>
                   <th>Unit Cost</th>
               </tr>
              </thead>
           <tbody>
                    <tr style="font-weight: 100;" ng-repeat="data in items | filter:{ TagName: filterTag, TagId: filterId} | filter:searchText" >
                    <td class="td-line-height" style="font-weight: 600;';">{{data.Product}}</td>
                    <td class="td-line-height">{{data.TagName}} </td>
                    <td class="td-line-height">{{data.UnitSize}} </td>
                    <td class="td-line-height">{{data.UnitCost | currency}} </td>
                  </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
       </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason *angular-datatables.js* is calling *isDataTable* function while *jquery.dataTables.js* defines this function as *fnIsDataTable*, so, to solve it, just add

```
$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable = $.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable;
```

as your first line in your controller.

here is the error message:

```
VM892 angular.js:9563TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable is not a function
  at Object.renderDataTable (VM1134 angular-datatables.js:753)
  at Object.hideLoadingAndRenderDataTable (VM1134 angular-datatables.js:773)
  at VM1134 angular-datatables.js:910
  at VM892 angular.js:13777
  at completeOutstandingRequest (VM892 angular.js:4236)
  at VM892 angular.js:4537
```

updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/TgpWLuiTDbb91yJeHYoX?p=preview

Comment: Chrome developer tool or FireFox firebug, under console section, then I checked http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js and https://rawgit.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/dev/dist/angular-datatables.js files

Comment: I removed my original comment on how you found the error, but thanks for the helpful response!